# Rendering issues when applying custom <select> in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, html-select

I am using `bootstrap-select.min.js` with `bootstrap 3` to apply custom theme to my select tag. It has a simple jQuery function to apply the theme.

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

What happening is that this only works inside `$(document).ready(function()`. So it is showing the default HTML layout of `<select>` before applying the custom theme. It looks bad and also makes the layout of my bootstrap navigation bar uneven.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/SDWhr/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works after applying it inside `window.load` function instead of `document.ready`

```
$(window).load(function() 
{
   $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
});
```